# Non encoded percent in URL

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting, urlencode

I have a php script, and someone else is generating URL-s to it.

And that person didn't knew the % character has to be encoded so i have the problem that apache is refusing those requests. (Bad Request)

So my question is, how do i convert a URL like 
site.com/search/one two %
into a valid 
site.com/search/one two %25

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be helpful?

```
preg_replace('/%(\D)/', '%25$1');
```

This should replace a % followed by anything but a number with the encoded version.

I will edit this post later to make it exclude only if there are not two numbers after the % but this may give an idea.

Comment: I guess this would work, but as rewrite_url, because the links are already formed, and the scrip is not executed because apache throws bad request

Comment: Oh right, you don't have access to the script before the request is sent... Sorry, I don't know anything you could do there in that case, apart from trying to have the sending script changed.